# "An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket" when attempting to connect

Tags: python, sockets, networking, tcp, ip

After finishing a tutorial on how to make a simple terminal based chatroom in python, I wanted to add more features, most notably a simple GUI. The Progress was going smoothly, but I ran into a roadblock. "connect" button is supposed to store the input text fields for the ip and port and define them into variables, then they will be used to connect to the server. You can see this all in "def connect():". When clicking the "connect" button, I get the error of:

```
"Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\censored\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "c:\Users\censored\Desktop\Chatroom\client.py", line 32, in connect
    client.connect((ip, int(port)))
OSError: [WinError 10038] An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket"
```

Also, ignore the "receive" button, I think I am going to get rid of it.

Client script:

```
import socket
import threading
import tkinter as tk



root= tk.Tk()

canvas1 = tk.Canvas(root, width = 600, height = 600)
canvas1.pack()

entry1 = tk.Entry (root) 
canvas1.create_window(200, 140, window=entry1)

entry2 = tk.Entry (root) 
canvas1.create_window(200, 240, window=entry2)

entry3 = tk.Entry (root) 
canvas1.create_window(200, 340, window=entry3)

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

def connect():
        
        ip = entry1.get()

        port = entry2.get()

        

        
        client.connect((ip, int(port)))

button1 = tk.Button(text='connect', command=connect)
canvas1.create_window(200, 180, window=button1)

nickname = entry3.get()

print(nickname)

def receive():
    while True:
        try:
            
            message = client.recv(1024).decode('ascii')
            if message == 'NICK' :
                client.send(nickname.encode('ascii'))
            else:
                print(message)
        except:
            print("ERROR!")
            client.close()
            break


button2 = tk.Button(text='receive', command=receive)
canvas1.create_window(200, 400, window=button2)

def write():
    while True:
        message = f'{nickname}: {input("")}'
        client.send(message.encode('ascii'))

receive_thread = threading.Thread(target=receive)
receive_thread.start()

write_thread = threading.Thread(target = write)
write_thread.start()

root.mainloop()
```

Here is also my server script, which is working fine:

```
import threading
import socket

ip = input("Input server ip: ")
portid = input("Input server port: ")

host = ip
port = int(portid)

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind((host, port))
server.listen()

clients = []
nicknames = []

def broadcast(message):
    for client in clients:
        client.send(message)

def handle(client):
    while True:
        try:
            message = client.recv(1024)
            broadcast(message)
        except:
            index = clients.index(client)
            clients.remove(client)
            client.close()
            nickname = nicknames[index]
            broadcast(f'{nickname} has left'.encode('ascii'))
            nicknames.remove(nickname)
            break

def receive():
    while True:
        client, address = server.accept()
        print(f"Connected with {str(address)}")

        client.send('NICK'.encode("ascii"))
        nickname = client.recv(1024).decode('ascii')
        nicknames.append(nickname)
        clients.append(client)

        print(f'Nickname of the newly connected client is {nickname} :)')
        broadcast(f'{nickname} joined the chat'.encode('ascii'))
        client.send('Connected!'.encode('ascii'))

        thread = threading.Thread(target = handle, args=(client,))
        thread.start()

print("server listening..")
receive()
```

Answer (score 0):

The client immediately does `receive_thread.start()`; as it's not connected, `receive()` errors out with `client.close()`; with the closed `client` socket it's no longer possible to `connect`.

You probably shouldn't start the receive thread before a connection is made.